Mi fondo es afectado al agregar contenido
Agregue el fondo en un archivo css con la etiqueta body, quiero agregar una imágen del lado izquierdo y a la derecha agregar texto pero al momento de ajustar la anchura y el largo de la imagen el fondo se ve afectado al usar div, el código que agregue no se ve afectado, si existe algún otro método que me diga por favor


body {
  background-image: url('https://cinepremiere.com.mx/wp-content/uploads/2018/08/Ya-veremos-critica-1024x559.jpg');
  background-size: contain;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center center;
}

img {
  width: 600px;
  height: 860px;
}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Aboutme</title>
</head>

<body>
  <img src="https://occ-0-1229-116.1.nflxso.net/dnm/api/v6/LmEnxtiAuzezXBjYXPuDgfZ4zZQ/AAAABff0mlOaXL0V901UEg1Z2spMXkJIoUsHJltf_5ZV8X7HQr-FxLu70b-2sXtFKk_Ll5xhdfNCuiMuThqlQt-QPPM68qw3_HTZOT-qOtYnNlot.png?r=d8d">
  <p>edqwldqw</p>
</body>

</html>




De cual div hablas ? ahi no hay un div.

Déjanos saber si la respuesta fue de utilidad para ti aceptándola y dándole al upvote. En caso contario deja un comentario indicando si no te funciona.

Puedes usar flexbox para lograr lo que deseas hacer.
Dejo comentarios en el código para tratar de explicar los cambios que hice. Si tienes dudas al respecto deja un comentario.
Usé imagenes de picsum photos para que sean visibles en el snnipet. Revisa el código y ajústalo a tu proyecto.


body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  background-image: url(https://picsum.photos/seed/picsum/2000/1800);
  background-size: cover; /* Usamos la propiedad cover en lugar de contain */
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center; /* No es necesario repetir center */
}

.content {
  display: flex; /* Usamos flexbox para distribuir los elementos */
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  height: 100vh;
  padding: 20px;
  box-shadow: 0 4px 8px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
}

img {
  max-width: 300px;
  height: auto;
  margin-right: 20px;
}

.text {
  max-width: 600px;
}

h1 {
  margin-top: 0;
}

p {
  margin-bottom: 0;
}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Aboutme</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="CSS/sobremi.css">
</head>

<body>
  <!-- Agregar un div que contendrá la imagen y el texto -->
  <div class="content">
    <img src="https://picsum.photos/400/300">
    <!-- Y un div adicional que contendrá los elementos de texto -->
    <div class="text">
      <h1>Título del Texto</h1>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vivamus facilisis, orci et commodo dapibus, massa metus rutrum purus, eget aliquam sem metus vel ipsum. Aenean sodales tincidunt lobortis. Morbi hendrerit odio metus, a mollis massa pellentesque
        ultrices. Donec viverra id elit sit amet blandit. Phasellus consequat laoreet odio a sodales. Nam facilisis odio tincidunt scelerisque eleifend. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia curae; Sed libero
        lectus, maximus porttitor euismod ac, viverra non lectus.</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>



